# Mını PCIe Video capture Card - Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have DVP-7031e analog camera vide capture card (Mını Pcıe). I use Python 3.x
I want to access to analog camera via this video capture card. Does Opencv support to Mını PCIe video grabber card?

Comment: Maybe ask the manufacturer. If you can get the image into your PC, using their SDK, it should be easy enough to process the images with OpenCV.

Comment: I asked, Manufacturer sent to me c++ SDK but I use python.I can access analog camera via /dev/video0 easy. Why I can not access when I use mini PCIE slot